# Derivative with respect to a coordiante differential (geodesic equation)

Tags: tensor-calculus, relativity, differentiation, action, geodesics

If the arc length is chosen to be the action integral, that is $$ S=\int \sqrt {g_{kn}\frac{dx^k}{ds} \frac{dx^n}{ds}} dx  \tag{11.13} $$

Then Lagrangian is given by $$L=\sqrt {g_{kn}\frac{dx^k}{ds} \frac{dx^n}{ds}} \tag{11.14}$$

Applying the EL Equation $$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial x^m}- \frac{d}{ds}\frac{\partial L}{\partial (\frac{dx^m}{ds})}=0 \tag{11.15}$$

Giving
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial (\frac{dx^m}{ds})}=\frac{1}{2} (g_{kn}\frac{dx^k}{ds}\frac{dx^n}{ds})^{-\frac{1}{2}} 2g_{ml}\frac{dx^l}{ds}=g_{ml}\frac{dx^l}{ds} \tag{11.16}$$

However I was not able to see how both $\frac{1}{2} (g_{kn}\frac{dx^k}{ds}\frac{dx^n}{ds})^{-\frac{1}{2}} 2g_{ml}\frac{dx^l}{ds} $and $g_{ml}\frac{dx^l}{ds}$ were obtained. (I tried to apply the chain rule but the result was no where near this)

Comment: The first equality seems to me just ordinary chain rule, what other result did you get? Second equality is due to the fact that $g_{kn}\dot{x}^k\dot{x}^n$ is normalized to 1 when EoM holds, which is additional condition on parameter s.

Comment: Which reference?